# Extract ISODate as date string from MongoDb using Java driver 3.8

Tags: java, mongodb, datetime, mongodb-query, mongo-java-driver

Below is mongo collection:

```
{"_id":ObjectId("5a8f997fcdc2960adae4f919"),"COBDate":ISODate("2018-02-15T18:30:00.000Z"),"Version":1}
```

Code to extract COBDate from mongo

```
MongoCollection<Document>collection=db.getCollection(collectionName);
String jsonMessage=collection.find().iterator().next().toJson;
JSONObject message=new JSONObject(jsonMessage);
String date=message.get(COBDate).toString();
```

But it extracted the value of `COBDate` as `{"$date":1518719400000}`.

Can someone help me to get it in some date format like `"2018-02-15T18:30:00.000Z"`?

mongo Driver 3.8 and mongodb 3.2.6 i am getting above issue. 
mongo driver 3.6 working fine...

Solution:-

```
          // or use a connection string
          MongoClientURI connectionString = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost:27017");
          MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);

          MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("testdb");

          MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("user");

          //JsonWriterSettings writerSettings = new JsonWriterSettings(JsonMode.SHELL, true);           
          //System.out.println(doc.toJson(writerSettings));

          Document myDoc = collection.find().first();
          //System.out.println(myDoc.toJson(writerSettings));
          System.out.println("output (JSON) = " + com.mongodb.util.JSON.serialize(myDoc));
          System.out.println("output (JSON) = " + myDoc);
```

Comment: HI 
i am using java driver 3.8 and mongo db 3.2.6 above issue happen
but java driver 3.6 working fine any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you assign the `find` response to a `org.bson.Document` (rather than invoking `toJson()` on it) then you can read any of its attributes in a type specific manner. For a `Date` attribute this means invoking `document.getDate("...")`.

For example:

```
MongoCollection<Document> collection = mongoClient.getDatabase("...").getCollection("...");

Document document = collection.find().iterator().next();

// now you have a Date object ...
Date cob = document.getDate("COBDate");

/// ... which you can use _as is_ or format into a String as follows ...
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");

/// this will print: 2018-02-15T18:30:00.000Z
System.out.println(df.format(cob));
```

Comment: Don’t hardcode `Z` in the format pattern string, you will get incorrect result. And on the whole please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: It's not clear to me that the OP even needs to convert to a String, I think the key aspect of the answer is the use of `Document.getDate()` instead of `Document.toJson()`. Re the inclusion of `SimpleDateFormat`; I don't want to make any assumptions about what version of Java the OP is using.

Comment: I Found the solution

below code is working

System.out.println("output (JSON) = " + com.mongodb.util.JSON.serialize(myDoc));

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the toJson method call of the Document object.
From the java doc it says the JsonMode used by default is STRICT.

```
/**
     * Gets a JSON representation of this document using the {@link org.bson.json.JsonMode#STRICT} output mode, and otherwise the default
     * settings of {@link JsonWriterSettings.Builder} and {@link DocumentCodec}.
     *
     * @return a JSON representation of this document
     * @throws org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException if the document contains types not in the default registry
     * @see #toJson(JsonWriterSettings)
     * @see JsonWriterSettings
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public String toJson() {
        return toJson(new JsonWriterSettings());
    }
```

STRICT mode will return date values in Epoch format.If you need it in ISO format you should configure the JsonWriter to use RELAXED mode.

For example:-
pass the builder as argument of the toJson method.It should give you the date values in ISO Format

use    `myDoc.toJson(JsonWriterSettings.builder().build());` as the builder defaults to RELAXED mode

```
MongoCollection<Document>collection=db.getCollection(collectionName);
String jsonMessage=collection.find().iterator().next().toJson(JsonWriterSettings.builder().build());
JSONObject message=new JSONObject(jsonMessage);
String date=message.get(COBDate).toString();
```